# Run (async-)shell-command in view-mode

Tags: shell-command

How do I run `(async-)shell-command` (but no other `shell-mode` buffers) in `view-mode`?

Comment: I looked for (async-)shell-command-hook but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Do can define your another wrapper function that calls `async-shell-command` which enables the `view-mode` after calling that function.

```el
(defun my/async-shell-command (command &optional output-buffer error-buffer)
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-shell-command "Async shell command: " nil nil
            (let ((filename
                   (cond
                (buffer-file-name)
                ((eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
                 (dired-get-filename nil t)))))
              (and filename (file-relative-name filename))))
    current-prefix-arg
    shell-command-default-error-buffer))
  ;; call the original function
  (async-shell-command command output-buffer error-buffer)
  ;; switch to the shell command output buffer
  (switch-to-buffer "*Async Shell Command*")
  ;; enable `view-mode'
  (view-mode))
```

and bind that to the default `async-shell-command` binding `M-&`.

*Note that the `(interactive (list ..))` portion of the wrapper funciton is copied directly from the source code for `async-shell-command`. It's useful to retain the input arguments of the original function when writing a wrapper around it.  The same applies if you were to use `advice-add` (emacs 24.4+) instead.*

Similar thing can be done for `shell-command` too.

Comment: Awesome! I'll try this out tomorrow. From reading your code though I'm guessing that the last three lines would be enough, right? I don't quite understand the interactive part.

Comment: @MattiasBengtsson Nope, you will need the interactive part too. I have simply copied that portion from the source code. That portion is important as it creates the mechanism for entering the shell command in the minibuffer.

Comment: Did you test it? I'm wondering whether you won't get errors for trying to print on a readonly buffer.

Comment: @Malabarba I tested this to work as the OP wants. Calling this function, executes the async command as entered in the minibuffer and then makes the async buffer read-only (`view-mode`). So when you try to type in that buffer, you won't be able to. Re-executing the same command, discards the old async buffer and shows the new content, again making that read-only.

Comment: Hm it doesn't quite work. The original async-shell-command will popup and then the switch-to-buffer call will add a new view of the buffer. The old view won't be in view-mode.

See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DI4I-KOGA90

Hm, I wonder if it would be possible to construct an advice around (async-)shell-command? I'll try that out later this week.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there are no shell command hooks, an alternative is to use [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html). All asynchronous processes need to specify a [sentinel function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html), which in the case of shell commands is `shell-command-sentinel`:

```el
(define-advice shell-command-sentinel (:after (process _msg) my-view-output)
  "Enable `view-mode' in `*Async Shell Command*' buffers."
  (let ((buffer (process-buffer process)))
    (and (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal))
         (buffer-live-p buffer)
         (with-current-buffer buffer
           (view-mode)))))
```

Synchronous shell commands, on the other hand, all go through the command `shell-command-on-region`:

```el
(define-advice shell-command-on-region (:after (&rest _) my-view-output)
  "Enable `view-mode' in `*Shell Command Output*' buffer."
  (let ((buffer (get-buffer "*Shell Command Output*")))
    (when (buffer-live-p buffer)
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (view-mode)))))
```

The latter advice is actually a bit more brittle than the former because it hard-codes the buffer name, but it should work for most cases. You should tweak it to suit your needs and use of shell commands.